# Proof of Generalized Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability

I have encountered the following "generalised" form of the Law of Total Probability:

$$P(A|B) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(A|B\cap E_i)P(E_i|B),$$

where the $E_i$'s form a partition of the sample space. I am not sure how to prove this? I tried using Bayes' Theorem, but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking the equation you're trying to prove and getting rid of all the conditional probabilities using the definition $P(X|Y) = P(X \cap Y)/P(Y)$. After doing that you're trying to prove
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{P(A \cap B\cap E_i)\, P(B\cap E_i)}{P(E_i \cap B)\, P(B)}\,,$$
which can be written more simply as
$$P(A \cap B) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A \cap B \cap E_i)\,.$$
This last equation is true because $\{E_1, E_2, \ldots\}$ is a partition of your sample space.